# Why does reading JSON from database with Perl warn about "wide characters"?

Tags: json, perl

I'm reading data from a database using Perl (I'm new to Perl), one of the columns is a JSON array. The problem I'm having is that when I try to read the data in the JSON I get an error "Wide character in subroutine entry".

Table:

> id | name | date | data

Sample data.

> { "duration":"24", "name":"My Test","visible":"1" }

```
use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $current_connection = $DATABASE_CONNECTION->prepare( "SELECT  * FROM data WHERE syt = 'area1' " ); 

$current_connection->execute();

while( my $db_data = $current_connection->fetchrow_hashref() )
{
    my $name = $db_data->{name}; 
    my $object = decode_json($db_data->{data});

    foreach my $key (sort keys %{$object}) { 
        my $result;
        $pages .= "<p> $result->{$key}->{name} </p>";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you strore UTF-8 strings in the database? Is the DBD driver correctly configured to support it? Do you decode the values before passing them to `decode_json`?

Comment: You would not get that error from the example you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error means a character greater than 255 was passed to a sub expecting a string of bytes.

When stored in the database, the string is encoded using some character encoding, possibly UTF-8. You appear to have decoded the text (e.g. by using `mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1`), producing a string of Unicode Code Points. However, `decode_json` expects UTF-8.

The solution is to use `from_json` or `JSON->new->decode` instead of `decode_json`; these expect decoded text (a string of UCP).

You can verify that this is the issue using `sprintf '%vX', $json`.

For example,

- If you get `E9` and `2660` for "`é`" and "`♠`",

  That's their UCP. Use `from_json` or `JSON->new->decode`.
- If you get `C3.A9` and `E2.99.A0` for "`é`" and "`♠`",

  That's their UTF-8. Use `decode_json` or `JSON->new->utf8->decode`.